# Get latest tiles from TileMill's tile server in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tiles, tilemill, cache

My leaflet app gets the tiles from TileMill's tile server in the standard way:

```
L.tileLayer('http://<myip>/tile/SteveCountryVic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { ... });
```

These tiles are often old, not showing the latest styles. I'm not sure if they're coming from TileMill itself or some intermediary cache.

I notice that TileMill includes an 'updated' parameter:

```
http://<myip>/tile/SteveCountryVic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?updated=1372394902000
```

Manually copying that updated timestamp means I get the latest timestamp. But what's a good way to not have to manually update the URL every time I change the style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updated=1372394902000` Parameter is basically the Unix epoch time in milseconds.

Your tile is being requested with a HTTP GET request. What you need to know about Http Get's is that you can pile on any arbitrary parameters at the end of a Get Request, and if the parameter does not make sense to the server, it will ignore it.

This fact is exploited often, to make sure that you get a new response from the server, and not from the Client Browser's cache.

If you had request for say: http://example.com/foo/bar.png, the browser would see if the resource from this url was present in the cache. If it is, then a request is Not made, and the resource is served from the cache.

Hence we tag an arbitrary parameter with the timestamp.Every time you make a new request, the timestamp has changed, and it becomes a new URL for the browser.

So in short you can do it like this in JavaScript

```
var ts=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0);
var url="http://<myip>/tile/SteveCountryVic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?updated="+ts;
```

Hence Automatically, with every time your App runs, the new timestamp is used, and the latest tile is called.

A word of warning though: This will make your application slow, since none of the tiles will every be cached by your browser.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. So after a bit of testing, I see that TileMill doesn't even pay attention to the updated parameter. Just a browser/cache trick - cool.

Comment: One nifty thing about this is that by changing the 1000.0, you can tweak the cache expiry. eg, replace it with (1000.0 * 86400.0) and tiles will be re-fetched once a day.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using (1000.0 * 86400.0) because you won't get the day exactly. There are other ways of getting the current Date from JavaScript's Date. Additionally I would suggest that if you are in control of the tiles, you can simply increment the parameter by 1, every-time you update the tiles.

Comment: Well, incrementing the parameter manually is what I do at the moment, but it's not much fun.